# How are network file system mount paths defined in Lion (apart from Directory Services)?

Tags: macos, mount, autofs

Checking Directory Services for network file system mounts, i.e.

```
sudo dscl . -list /Mounts
```

and

```
sudo dscl . -readall /Mounts
```

returns nothing, yet the `/etc/fstab` file is deprecated in Lion. Why is `dscl` returning nothing and where are the mounts defined if they aren’t by Directory Services?

Comment: Good question – from what I gather from [this blog post](http://blog.localdigi.de/2011/09/04/smb-freigaben-unter-os-x-lion-automatisch-einbinden/) (German), auto mounts in Lion need to be defined via references in the AutoMounter master table, `/etc/auto_master`.

Comment: Launchd controls the boot process for several versions of Mac OS X. The Mounts part of directory services is empty by default. Are you looking to make new mounts or figure out how Lion is booting?

Comment: Looking how to configure mounts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OS X uses the **Autofs stack** to mount network file systems. Keith Winston has a good [introduction to Autofs on OS X](http://lowendmac.com/ed/winston/09kw/intro-to-autofs.html) stating that:

> OS X uses an autofs code stack based on Sun's Solaris version of Unix. Many of the advanced features are not documented very well, and this can be an issue unless you are familiar with Solaris. I was not and had to do quite a bit of digging.
>
> Autofs is often used in enterprise environments to set up network-based home directories and other network mounts for users at login. It can also dynamically mount network shares on access.

By default, Autofs mounts network files systems defined via Directory Services, those defined in `/etc/fstab` and [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System_%28protocol%29) file systems, all accordingly to its master table, `/etc/auto_master`.

Your call to `dscl` returns nothing because no mounts have been defined in Directory Services (no surprise there). If you want to define mount points not covered by Autofs default configuration without resorting to Directory Services or the deprecated `/etc/fstab`, you will have to add a mapping (via a auto_* file) to `auto_master`. For the technical background, refer to the post linked above; there is a good “how to” add auto mounts for [SMB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) mounts in [this Mac OS X Hints post](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100203124656707).

Comment: I don't know how it had me under this account, the first time I posted here it just asked for my name. I would love to accept this answer, how do I access an account just by username?

Comment: @rubixibuc:according to [the Meta answer most closely related to the question I could find](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82416/can-registered-user-accept-answers-on-questions-created-before-registration), you’ll have to flag the question for moderator attention and ask or the accounts to be merged.

Comment: I flagged it :-), I'll accept it as soon as I can

Comment: I'm looking into the merge for you...

Comment: The merge is live @rubixibuc - you should be good to go.